# Visual Studio code ( VSC) and System console

Tags: python

I realized that if we launch blender from VSC ( Visual Studio Code ) we cant access the system console.
That's maybe a dumb question but I'm wondering why ?
We can see error and everything in VSC but not in blender. That's a bit annoying but I'm wondering is it's normal or if it should be on both of them ?
[image]

Comment: Yes it is normal